How to assign product post author as seller/vendor
I am utilizing JetFormBuilder to create products for a multi-vendor marketplace using Dokan directly from a front-end form. However, I am encountering an issue where I am struggling to assign the product post author as the corresponding seller/vendor. How can I do this with a hook to store product post author as vendor seller? I want to fill this vendor field with product author name who submitted the product using Jet Form.
I tried this one:
// Add post type support for 'author' to WooCommerce products
function prefix_add_author_woocommerce() {
    add_post_type_support('product', 'author');
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'prefix_add_author_woocommerce');

// Assign product author if not already set
function prefix_assign_product_author($post_id, $post, $update) {
    if ('product' === $post->post_type && !get_post_meta($post_id, '_product_author', true)) {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_author', $current_user->display_name);
    }
}
add_action('save_post_product', 'prefix_assign_product_author', 10, 3);

// Add a new column to the admin products list for the author
function prefix_author_column_to_product_list($columns) {
    $new_columns = array();
    foreach ($columns as $key => $title) {
        if ($key == 'date') { // Put the author column before the date column
            $new_columns['author'] = 'Author';
        }
        $new_columns[$key] = $title;
    }
    return $new_columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-product_columns', 'prefix_author_column_to_product_list');

// Populate the new author column in the admin products list
function prefix_author_column_content_to_product_list($column, $post_id) {
    if ('author' == $column) {
        $author_name = get_post_meta($post_id, '_product_author', true);
        echo esc_html($author_name);
    }
}
add_action('manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'prefix_author_column_content_to_product_list', 10, 2);


How can I programmatically set a user as a seller for a product using their user ID and the product ID?

The current issue is that when a user fills out the form using the Jet Form Builder, the product author is not stored in the Dokan vendor field; the vendor field appears empty.
